# Codeception API testing response comes back as 'N/A'

Tags: api, laravel, response, codeception

I am writing an API using Laravel and Codeception as my testing framework.

I am having trouble getting Codeception to come back with a response code that I can pick up from Codeception as well as a JSON response.

I've written a simple test to get a list of users from a GET request.

The test is as follows:

```
$I = new ApiGuy($scenario);
$I->wantTo("access API methods if I'm authenticated as a User");

$I->sendGET('users');

$I->seeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
```

I can see the results coming though ok, just cant seem to get the response code.

The route that generates the response is as follows:

```
Route::get('users', function() {

    $users = User::all();
    return Response::json($users->toArray(), 200);
});
```

The response from Codeception is:

```
Modules: PhpBrowser, REST, ApiHelper, Laravel4, Db, Filesystem
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to only access api methods if i'm authenticated as a user (UserAuthCept.php)       
Scenario:
* I send get "users"
  [Request] GET http://myapp-api.local/users
  [Response] [{"id":1,"firstname":"First","lastname":"User","email":"firstuser@test.com","phone":"","login":0,"status":0,"username":"firstuser","created_at":"2014-03-17 14:55:29","updated_at":"2014-03-17 14:55:29"},{"id":2,"firstname":"Second","lastname":"User","email":"seconduser@test.com","phone":"","login":0,"status":0,"username":"seconduser","created_at":"2014-03-17 14:55:30","updated_at":"2014-03-17 14:55:30"}]
  [Headers] {"date":["Mon, 17 Mar 2014 17:50:22 GMT"],"server":["Apache"],"x-powered-by":["PHP\/5.4.26-1~dotdeb.0"],"cache-control":["no-cache"],"x-frame-options":["SAMEORIGIN"],"set-cookie":["laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Im9PZ09qYzdZSWI2bnRsTXFxOUJBelFRVUpEVXFKZVp3VFlMU1h1c3lkRG89IiwidmFsdWUiOiJwSDdCVzlMSjU5SERwWmNENzBsOUFaRExXbit3SUcxSG9vRmpRcGN2cXNrK2kzVU1NT0FaTGdsNGZObG1NT01nN01QdlZXU2FCdGpPcjMzY0dJak1hdz09IiwibWFjIjoiOWRmZDEwNGVhNWQ5MWQyMmRiMTBiOWVjNGNkYjA4ZmFlYzg4NjBmYjhjM2Q2ZmRlNWQ3NzlkY2I0NDhlOTVkYiJ9; expires=Mon, 17-Mar-2014 19:50:22 GMT; path=\/; httponly"],"vary":["Accept-Encoding"],"transfer-encoding":["chunked"],"content-type":["application\/json"]}
  [Status] 200
* I see response is json 
* I see response code is 200
 FAIL 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 1.05 seconds, Memory: 9.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) Failed to only access api methods if i'm authenticated as a user in UserAuthCept.php
Sorry, I couldn't see response code is 200:
Failed asserting that 'N/A' matches expected 200.

Scenario Steps:
3. I see response code is 200
2. I see response is json 
1. I send get "users"


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: I can see where the 'N/A' is coming from:

`protected function getResponseStatusCode()
    {
        // depending on Symfony version
        $response = $this->client->getInternalResponse();
        if (method_exists($response, 'getStatus')) return $response->getStatus();
        if (method_exists($response, 'getStatusCode')) return $response->getStatusCode();
        return "N/A";
    }
`

So i've tried adding in the Symfony2 module but its now saying module requirements are not met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the code and looking at all instances of seeResponseCodeIs, realised it was executing the 'Framework' version. Took out the Laravel4 module and it now works!

Comment: I would love a solution for this that didn't involve removing the Laravel4 module - I'm using it to set environment, filters, etc before running the tests to my API.

Comment: In case anybody else is having this issue, I resolved this problem by moving the Laravel4 module in the suite config to the start of the array - it looks like it needs to be loaded before the REST module.